# Import existing animation file to unity web player model

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to import an existing .anim file to an existing unity model.
I know how do so it in Unity, and build into a HTML file, but I'm wondering is there a method to do it just using unityscript or javascript?
I mean using javascript to load an .anim file into the model in unity web player, if there is any solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resource.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) allows you to do just that.

```
var mdl : GameObject = Resources.Load("Animations/"+ animationFolder+"/" + aName);

    if (!mdl) {

        Debug.LogError("Missing animation asset: Animations/" + animationFolder+"/"+aName + " could not be found.");

    }  else {

        var aClip = mdl.animation.clip;
        charAnimation.AddClip(aClip, aName);
        Debug.Log(charAnimation[aName].name + " loaded from resource file " + animationFolder + "/" + aName + ". Length check: " + charAnimation[aName].length);    

    }
```